# Is it possible to re-create this logic in SQL with a different variable type?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Currently I have this WHERE clause in a SQL script in SQL Server.

```
where (isNull(@InsuranceKey,isnull(InsuranceKey,0)) = isnull(InsuranceKey,0))
```

Currently `@InsuranceKey` is a single `INT` being passed in, and `InsuranceKey` is also an `INT` in the database.

However, this is changing so that `@InsuranceKey` is becoming `@InsuranceKeys`, a `VARCHAR(MAX)` and comma delimited list of insurance keys.

How is it possible to re-create this logic in another way? I've been struggling with it.

So far I believe:

```
((@InsuranceKeys <> '' AND InsuranceKey in (Select ID From GetIntegerList(@InsuranceKeys))) OR (@InsuranceKeys = ''))
```

is an accurate logical equivalent of :

```
WHERE isNull(@InsuranceKey, InsuranceKey) = InsuranceKey
```

But I'm struggling to get further than that.

Comment: you don't really need the `@InsuranceKeys <> ''` assuming `GetIntegerList` returns integer and not character representations of integers because the empty string will automatically not be in the list.

Comment: @GB Well that isn't the logical equivalent I'm going for, is it?. I need to also do an isNull check of InsuranceKey against 0 (as is shown by the original WHERE clause at the top of the post) but I'm not sure how to get that in there

Unless I've just confused myself.

Comment: inner join with a table returned function which returns IDs from InsuranceKeys. Without knowing selection, checking joined query with if exists would go...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm mistaken the logical equivalent of your statement

```
where (isNull(@InsuranceKey,isnull(InsuranceKey,0)) = isnull(InsuranceKey,0))
```

is

```
where InsuranceKey is null or InsuranceKey = InsuranceKey or InsuranceKey = @InsuranceKey
```

because those are the scenarios you are handling.

You could possibly re-write that as

```
where InsuranceKey is null or InsuranceKey = coalesce(@InsuranceKey,InsuranceKey)
```

So, if you now have a list of comma separated InsuranceKey values which you are passing to a function that returns list of InsuranceKey values then possibly something like this would work

```
where InsuranceKey is null or InsuranceKey in (Select ID 
                                                From GetIntegerList(@InsuranceKeys)
                                                Union
                                                select InsuranceKey)
```